# How can I target the child elements in this Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, popup

I have a site with a list and I want to make it so that when you click an item there's a popup window.

I'm following this here - https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_popup.asp

This is my HTML code -

```
              <div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">
                <ul class="matchup">
                  <li class="team team-top">2015 Clayton Kershaw</li>
                  <li class="team team-bottom">2017 Jose Altuve</li>
                </ul>
                <div class="popuptext" id="myPopup">
                  <h1>Popup Text</h1>
                </div>
              </div>
```

and my JS -

```
function myFunction() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

The popup works but the thing is I have 30 other lists on the page and I don't want to create a function for each one.

How can I write the code so that it targets the child elements of the UL class "matchup" ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your work won't end even if you can open popup to click each list item.

You will need to make popup to show **different contents for each list item,** and you will soon recognize that you need powerful tools to make what you want.

There's plenty of tools, and the easiest one is [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/)

However, I'll just let you know just how to open the popup without `Vue.js`. Learn yourself at their website if you are interested at that.

first, remove `onclick` property from `.popup` element.

```html
<div class="popup">
  <ul class="matchup">
    <li class="team team-top">2015 Clayton Kershaw</li>
    <li class="team team-bottom">2017 Jose Altuve</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="popuptext" id="myPopup">
    <h1>Popup Text</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then, replace your javascript code to this.

```js
// this `togglePopup` function works similarly with your `myFunction` function, but it caches the element selecting result for better performance.
const togglePopup = (() => {
  const element = document.querySelector('#myPopup');
  console.log(element)
  return () => {
    element.classList.toggle("show");
  }
})();

// this finds all `li` elements inside `.matchup` element and make to execute `togglePopup` when one of those are clicked by user.
document.querySelectorAll('.matchup li').forEach(e => {
  e.addEventListener('click', () => {
    togglePopup()
  })
})
```